# Using Lime for a LSTM

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, lstm, lime, xai

Hey Stackoverflow Community,

I am trying to apply the XAI-Tool Lime on my LSTM-Model.
I am doing a forecasting task in the energy sector. The data is a CSV-file, therefore I had to change the shape of the data from a 2d table to a 3d, so I can use it for the LSTM-Model. So I try to clean up the data a little bit, deleting some variables which are most of the time "nan", to get a better performence.

The Model is working fine, the loss isn't the best, but I didn't tune any hyperparameters yet - so this is all good.

```
import os
import random
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


f = open(os.path.expanduser("/Users/x/Turbine_Data.csv"))
df = pd.read_csv(f)

df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': "Index"}, inplace=True)
df = df.set_index("Index")

df = df.drop(["WTG","Blade1PitchAngle","Blade2PitchAngle","Blade3PitchAngle","ControlBoxTemperature"], axis = 1)
df = df.dropna(subset=["WindSpeed"])
threshold = 3
df = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1] - threshold)
df = df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
nan_counts = df.isna().sum()

#print(nan_counts)
print(df.head(3))

def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
 n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
 df = DataFrame(data)
 cols, names = list(), list()
 for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
     cols.append(df.shift(i))
     names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
 for i in range(0, n_out):
     cols.append(df.shift(-i))
     if i == 0:
         names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
     else:
         names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
 agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
 agg.columns = names
 if dropnan:
     agg.dropna(inplace=True)
 return agg
 
values = df.values
values = values.astype('float32')
df = series_to_supervised(values, 1, 1)
df.drop(df.columns[[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]], axis=1, inplace=True)

#print(df.head())

df = df.values
inputs, outputs = df[:, :-1], df[:, -1]
inputs_train, inputs_val, outputs_train, outputs_val = train_test_split(inputs,outputs,test_size=.2,random_state=42)
inputs_train = inputs_train.reshape((inputs_train.shape[0], 1, inputs_train.shape[1]))
inputs_val = inputs_val.reshape((inputs_val.shape[0], 1, inputs_val.shape[1]))
print(inputs_train.shape, outputs_train.shape, inputs_val.shape, outputs_val.shape)

def custom_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    predictions = estimator.predict(X)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
    return -mse

def create_lstm_model(units=150, learning_rate=0.001, batch_size=16, epochs=70):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units, input_shape=(inputs_train.shape[1], inputs_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(50))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

param_grid = {
    'units': [100, 150],
    'learning_rate': [0.0005, 0.001, 0.01],
    'batch_size': [16, 64, 96, 128],
    'epochs': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_lstm_model, verbose=0)

#RANDOM SEARCH FOR FINDING BEST HYPERPARAMETERS
#random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=keras_regressor, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=100, cv=2, scoring=make_scorer(custom_scorer), verbose=2, random_state=42)
#random_search.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train)
#print(random_search.best_params_)

#model = random_search.best_estimator_
m = model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train, epochs=60, batch_size=16, validation_data=(inputs_val, outputs_val), verbose=2, shuffle=False)


pyplot.plot(m.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(m.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Coming to my problem. I used Lime before to explain Regression Task, which worked fine. But I did not managed to apply LIME on the LSTM.

I might know, where the problem is. LSTM is using a 3D array, in my case e.g. (49285, 1, 16) for the input_train data. But LIME does expect a 2D array.
I already tried to reshape my data, nothing works fine.
The Doc of Lime did not help me out at all and I did not find any good example how to use LIME on a LSTM.

I tried this:

```
from lime.lime_tabular import LimeTabularExplainer
explainer = LimeTabularExplainer(training_data=inputs_train, mode="regression")

instance_idx = 0

input_instance = inputs_val[instance_idx].reshape((1, inputs_val.shape[1]))
predictions = model.predict(input_instance)
explanation = explainer.explain_instance(input_instance[0], model.predict)
explanation.show_in_notebook()
```

Do you have any idea how to get LIME working ? And you have any idea what's the major problem is? I am fully self taught, therefore some parts of my code might be a little filthy. I would be very grateful for tips and suggestions.

Thanks

Leo